# Does Google support structured data in crawlable AJAX?

Tags: seo, google, structured-data, crawlable-ajax

We've got a page, developed using AngularJS, that uses Pre-render as a service in order to serve static HTML to bots. This is using HTML5 mode in Angular, so the URLs look like standard urls. Essentially, how it works is, if a request comes in with an _escaped_fragment_ argument, we service a static HTML file.

Within this static HTML are all the structured data markup. We're trying to test this with the structured data helper. If I request a page with www.example.com/thisismypage, the structured data helper doesn't pick up anything. If I request it with www.example.com/thisismypage?_escaped_fragment_, it picks up all my structured data.

However - How can I confirm that this is the way Google will request my page? I was thinking the structured data helper would request the page the same way google would (ie. append the escaped_fragment bit transparently, but that does not seem to be the case).

Comment: Are you saying you're serving different content to bots vs regular visitors?

Comment: In a sense - To regular visitors, we serve an Angular app which builds the DOM using javascript. To bots who can't execute javascript, we render that DOM serverside and send it to them.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Google is either executing javascript (and not requesting via _escaped_fragement_), or requesting via _escaped_fragment, since I can view my structured data (ratings, etc) in Google's results for my page. I'm not sure which it is yet.